# Using numpy.loadtxt, how does one convert strings in the .txt file into integer values/floats?

Tags: python, file, text, numpy

So, I have a .txt file that I want to read into Pylab. The problem is that, when I try to do so using the `numpy.loadtxt("filename.txt")`, Pylab cannot read the numbers in the array in my file as float values (it returns the error: `cannot convert string to float`.).

I am not sure if there is something wrong with my syntax as above; when I remove the quotation marks inside the parentheses, `numpy.loadtxt(filename.txt)`, Pylab returns the error: filename is not defined.

Any suggestions on how to read a series of numbers saved in a .txt file into Pylab as an array of floats?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide sample lines in your `filename.txt` file. I guess you may need to read the doc for `numpy.loadtxt` [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html). There are some good examples on the document page.

BTW, the second command `numpy.loadtxt(filename.txt)` is wrong since you have not defined a variable `filename`.